# How to disable the "Your site has updated to WordPress x.y.z" admin email?

Tags: admin, email, notifications, automatic-updates

Using the automatic update of my self-hosted WordPress blogs, I configured automatic updates of both the WordPress core as well as WordPress plugins and themes ([through this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-updates-settings/)).

Whenever a core update occurs, I get an email like:

> *Your site has updated to WordPress 3.9.2*
>
> Howdy! Your site at http://example.org has been updated automatically
>   to WordPress 3.9.2.
>
> No further action is needed on your part. For more on version 3.9.2,
>   see the About WordPress screen: http://example.org/wp-admin/about.php
>
> If you experience any issues or need support, the volunteers in the
>   WordPress.org support forums may be able to help.
>   https://wordpress.org/support/
>
> The WordPress Team

I understand that I can [completely disable administrative notification emails](http://mandarapte.com/wordpress/enable-disable-receiving-wordpress-admin-mail-notifications-how/) but I would prefer to only disable the above notification.

**Therefore my question is:**

How to disable update notification emails in WordPress?

Comment: I wrote a lightweight plugin to disable all update notifications (core, themes, plugins). It's open source so if you prefer you can also just copy the code and insert it into your functions.php. Check it out: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-all-update-notifications/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `functions.php` add:

```
add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that I asked my question on a WordPress _development_ support site. Actually being a WordPress _user_, there is currently no way to achieve what I want without doing some PHP programming, right?

Comment: Right, unfortunately WordPress doesn't provide any GUI to control core emails.

Comment: But don't worry this really is no rocket science. All you need to do is add this one line at the end of your functions.php file using a text editor (for example notepad on windows)

Answer (score 7):

An alternative is to create a simple Must-use plugin so this doesn't depend on the theme.

Create a file `wp-content/mu-plugins/disable-auto-update-mail.php`

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Disable Auto Update Mails
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157056
Version: 1.0
Author: kraftner
AuthorURI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/47733/kraftner
*/

add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false' );
```

This can't be disabled by a user and works independent from any themes.