# WP auto-updates - no more email notification

Tags: email, wp-config, automatic-updates

I would love to block sending the notification email about new automatic update of wordpress (but I need to keep other emails working). Any ideas how to do that? I'm webmaster for more than 40 pages and that makes me crazy...

I've used following code in *wp-config.php* file, but it seems to be not working.

```
/** auto updates email **/
apply_filters( 'auto_core_update_send_email', false, $type, $core_update, $result );
```

Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Kind of. I need it for whole website not depending on theme used (and updates of themes). Solution to add `add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false' );` to _functions.php_ is working only for one theme which can't update anymore (or you have to redo it again)

Comment: Okay I added and alternative right there so we keep it all in one place: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/185232/47733